# 'yum update' without internet connectioon

Tags: fedora, yum

I have a PC and a laptop. my laptop is always updated, so for updating the PC I don't want to download the packages again for my PC. What I do is copying rpm files from `/var/cache/yum/i386/17/fedora/updates/packages` to the corresponding directory of the PC.

Is there a better/faster way to do this? can I say yum connect with ssh to laptop and get updated packages from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can certainly do is create a Yum repository containing the packages from your laptop and then point your PC to use that repository for getting packages.

You can create a repository by installing `createrepo` and then calling `createrepo --database /path/to/local/repository`. See [the RedHat documentation about creating a Yum repository](https://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Creating_a_Yum_Repository.html).

Once you've created a repository, you can point your Yum installation to it by creating a new file in `/etc/yum.repos.d`. Unfortunately, Yum only accepts http://, ftp://, or file:// URLs for the `baseurl` argument. So you'll either have to serve the repo over HTTP/FTP, or mount the laptop's filesystem using (for instance) [SSHFS](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html).

Answer (score 2):

Do you really have no Internet access on the computer, or (more likely) do you just wish to avoid downloading packages twice?

If the latter, one option is to use [IntelligentMirror](https://fedorahosted.org/intelligentmirror/) for your site. It will keep a copy of packages downloaded the first time, and the other computers will pick them up from your local IntelligentMirror. It hasn't been updated in several years, however it should still work.

You can also set up your own [private Fedora mirror](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Infrastructure/Mirroring#How_can_someone_make_a_private_mirror.3F), though this requires a bit of work.

Unless you're severely bandwidth-constrained (i.e. on dialup, or paying per megabyte) it's probably not worth any of the trouble and you shouldn't bother with any of this.